# Load resource from local directory with no class

Tags: kotlin

I frequently use code like this:

```
val sql = getResource(this.javaClass, "foo.sql")
```

or this:

```
val sql = getResource(::MyClass.javaClass, "foo.sql")
```

But with Kotlin, I find myself using *top-level* functions quite often where there is no object or class.

How would I do such a thing with a top-level function?

Comment: I guess you could do `var sql = getResource(object {}.javaClass, "foo.sql")`. Haven't tested though. Why not reference a known class in that package?

Answer (score 1):

The JDK does not define a static `getResource` method so I am not certain what library you are using to load resources this way but I suspect it is [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava). If not, I recommend using it as it has two `getResource` methods: one that takes a class as an argument and one that uses the [context class loader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html?is-external=true#getContextClassLoader--). Using the [latter](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/io/Resources.html#getResource-java.lang.String-) you can do the following:

```
import com.google.common.io.Resources.getResource

val sql = getResource("foo.sql")
```

Comment: Did you test it?

Comment: @lamberto-basti I did. Did you?